# Decrease the AWS SES limit to 100 mails per day

Tags: amazon-ses

How can I decrease the AWS SES mail sending limit to 100 mails per day? Currently it of 5000 per day.

Tried to setup IAM policies to limit the sending.

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": [
        "ses:SendEmail",
        "ses:SendRawEmail"
      ],
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {
        "NumericGreaterThan": {
          "ses:Max24HourSend": "50"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But showing  Invalid Service Condition Key: The condition key ses:Max24HourSend does not exist in the service ses. Use a valid condition key.